# Python, UUID, MySQL and Autobah/Twisted = assert error?

Tags: python, assert, autobahn

As I'm developing my app I've encountered an interesting situation.

I need a session token so after some research I decided to opt for:

```
sessionToken = uuid.UUID(bytes = M2Crypto.m2.rand_bytes(16))
```

I store this in MySQL table, as VARCHAR

When I read it (normal SELECT) from MySQL and try to send it as the first part of a sockets message:

```
mytoken = ''
content = 'test message'
mytoken = myResultRow[1] # read from MySQL

msg = mytoken + content
self.sendMessage(msg, False)
```

I get:

> self.sendMessage(msg, False)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autobahn/websocket/protocol.py", line 2421, in sendMessage
>
> assert(type(payload) == bytes)
>
> exceptions.AssertionError:

I got around this by:

```
msg = str(mytoken) + content
```

I can print the token but the problem is when I try to send it without it being in str() first...

Am I doing something wrong or is this 'normal' behaviour? Isn't a varchar from the database, stored in a variable that's declared an empty string a string...?